# HOTP/TOTP client token uniqueness

Tags: hmac, one-time-password, hamming-distance

Is it possible to use **TOTP** to generate tokens from multiple channels (where a channel is defined as a "user" using a certain shared key **K_c** for channel **c**), and in so doing identify the channel itself from the OTP?

For example, if two OTP's were generated with the both time sequence constant **i_0**, and shared secret keys **K_1** and **K_2** respectively, then:

`A = HMAC-SHA-1(K_1, i_0)` and
`B = HMAC-SHA-1(K_2, i_0)`

where A and B are the OTP's generated. My question is: would it be possible on the server side during validation to establish without the shadow of a doubt (mathematically speaking) that A is "linked" to channel 1 (**K_1**), and B to channel 2? In other words, every OTP generated using **K_1** will be different to those OTP's generated using **K_2** regardless of the truncation of the 160-bit output of HMAC.

My second question would be that if this is the case (the two "sequences" are different), can their difference be quantified in terms of say a Hamming distance?